# Stop SSH traffic being routed through VPN?

Tags: iptables, openvpn

As soon as I connect the VPN on the Virtual Machine I get disconnected, this is due to it routing the traffic through the tun0 vpn adapter.

I've tried to alter my ip tables to send any SSH packets to eth0 but it isn't working?

```
echo "201 novpn" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip rule add fwmark 65 table novpn
ip route add default via 178.62.0.1 dev eth0 table novpn
ip route flush cache
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j MARK --set-mark 65
iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

Also tried:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -p tcp --dport 22 \
  -j MARK --set-mark 65

echo 201 ssh5122.out >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip rule add fwmark 65 table ssh5122.out

ip route add default via 178.62.0.1 dev eth0 \
  dev table ssh5122.out
```

Comment: Do you want to use the VPN to route all traffic to the Internet, or only to particular subsets of ip adresses (aka `split tunneling`)? The solution depends on which goal you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Test the configuration below.

iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -o tun0 -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -i tun0 -p tcp --sport ssh -j ACCEPT